# Why byte and short division results in int in Java?

Tags: java, integer, division, integer-division

In Java, if we divide `byte`s, `short`s or `int`s, we always get an `int`. If one of the operands is `long`, we'll get `long`.

My question is - why does `byte` or `short` division not result in `byte` or `short`? Why always `int`?

Apparently I'm not looking for the "because JLS says so" answer, I am asking about the technical rationale for this design decision in the Java language.

Consider this code sample:

```
    byte byteA = 127;
    byte byteB = -128;
    short shortA = 32767;
    short shortB = -32768;
    int intA = 2147483647;
    int intB = - -2147483648;
    long longA = 9223372036854775807L;
    long longB = -9223372036854775808L;


    int byteAByteB = byteA/byteB;
    int byteAShortB = byteA/shortB;
    int byteAIntB = byteA/intB;
    long byteALongB = byteA/longB;

    int shortAByteB = shortA/byteB;
    int shortAShortB = shortA/shortB;
    int shortAIntB = shortA/intB;
    long shortALongB = shortA/longB;

    int intAByteB = intA/byteB;
    int intAShortB = intA/shortB;
    int intAIntB = intA/intB;
    long intALongB = intA/longB;

    long longAByteB = longA/byteB;
    long longAShortB = longA/shortB;
    long longAIntB = longA/intB;
    long longALongB = longA/longB;
```

`byteA` divided by `byteB` can't be anything but a byte, can it?
So why must `byteAByteB` be an `int`? Why can't `shortALongB` be `short`?
Why does `intALongB` have to be `long`, the result will always fit `int`, will it not?

**Update**

As @Eran pointed out, `(byte)-128/(byte)-1` results in `128` which does not fit a `byte`. But why not `short` then?

**Update 2**

Next, as @Eran pointed out (again), `(int) -2147483648 / (int) -1` also does not fit `int` but the result is nevertheless `int`, not `long`.

Comment: The rationale isn't technical, I'm quite sure.

Comment: The rule is the same in any C-like languages. Moreover JVM is written in C and C++ so it follows the same rule [Why are integer types promoted during addition in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29817927/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason is that machines usually have only add instructions for their native integer type (and floats). This is why for many languages the least used type in an arithmetic expression is `int` (usually the type that correspond in some way to the basic machine integer type).

For example, i386 spec says:

> ADD performs an integer addition of the two operands (DEST and SRC).
>   The result of the addition is assigned to the first operand (DEST),
>   and the flags are set accordingly. When an immediate byte is added to
>   a word or doubleword operand, the immediate value is sign-extended to
>   the size of the word or doubleword operand.

This means that internally any byte value is extended to an integer (or similar). After all this is reasonable as the processor is 32/64 bits and then perform any arithmetic in these sizes. If it could be possible to make arithmetic in bytes this is generally not considered as useful.

The JVM specs says that (for addition) you have : `iadd`, `ladd`, `fadd`, `dadd`. This just reflect the fact that underlying machines usually behave such. Any other choice could have been possible, probably at the price of performance degradation.

Answer (score 8):

> byteA divided by byteB can't be anything but a byte, can it?

It can be other than byte :

```
byteA = -128;
byteB = -1;
int div = byteA/byteB; // == 128, not a byte
```

Comment: Point taken. Why not `short` then?

Comment: `not a byte` .. in Java because it has no notion of unsigned .. 128 is still just a byte (`char`) in other languages that support unsigned

Comment: Note that `char` is a 16 bit *unsigned* type in Java. Nice.

Comment: @lexicore You got a point, and my example doesn't work when dividing Integer.MIN_VALUE by -1 (you'll get an int overflow, since the operands won't be promoted to long).

Comment: @Eran `-2147483648/-1` results in `-2147483648`. Cool. Breaks my logic for today.

Answer (score 3):

I *guess* it's something that was adopted from C, possibly via C++.

In those languages, an argument or arguments are *always* promoted to `int` if they are narrower types than an `int`. This happens *before* the expression is evaluated. Quite often it goes unnoticed since the resulting operation is converted to the type to which it is being assigned, and a compiler may well optimise out all the intermediate steps if there are no side effects.

In Java though it's not too pernicious. (In C and C++ it can catch you out: a multiplication of two large `unsigned short`s can overflow the `int`, the behaviour of which is *undefined*.)

Note that if one of the arguments is larger than an `int`, then the type of the expression is the largest of the arguments types.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the justification is that a simple rules creates least surprise.  The result is always the wider type of the two (minimum being `int`), it doesn't depend on the operation.

A better approach might be to always widen `+`, `*`, `-` unless explicitly (or perhaps implicitly) narrowed. i.e. don't do overflow or underflow unless you use a cast.  `/` for example could always be a `double` or `long` operation unless casted.

But C and thus Java doesn't do this.

In short, it has one simple rule for dealing with this, for better or worse.

---

See my rant here http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/inconsistent-operation-widen-rules-in.html

Comment: Are you sure it's the wider type of the two? My understanding is that that's the case if one of the arguments is larger than an `int`, but if both are `int`s or smaller, the result is always an `int`. But I'm not an expert on Java type promotion.

Comment: At least though it doesn't introduce a truck load of UB in Java ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba UB...?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: In your blog post: `char * char isn't a meaningful operation even though it is allowed`---I strongly disagree there. `char` is the only unsigned integer type in Java, we should all learn to love and cherish it!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik char is useful but using it to store non characters could be confusing.

Comment: Only until you get used to it. We're already using `byte` to store signed integers, so go figure :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're defining a variable of type byte, whatever you type across from it should be of type byte.

That means it can only be a **number** in the range of a byte (-128 to 127).

However, when you type in an **expression**, for ex. **byteA/byteB** that is not the same as typing in a **literal**, for ex. the number **127**.

This is the nature of Java - the **integer** is the default data type used for whole numbers.

By default when you're making an assignment of an **expression**, Java converts that into the default data type (integer) despite the fact that the result of the expression might be a valid value for a byte.

So what happens is that when you define a byte and assign an expression as the value of that byte, Java will need to convert it into an integer:

```
int byteAByteB = byteA / byteB;
```

However, you can get around that by casting the assigned expression and thus forsing Java to treat it as a byte.

```
byte byteAByteB = (byte) (byteA / byteB);
```

This way you're telling Java to treat that as a byte. (Can also be done with short, etc.)